# DocumentDb SELECT with JOIN not returning anything

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

My document in DocumentDb looks like this:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "timers":
  {
     "projectTimer":
     {
        "id": 234,
        "name": "My Project",
        "startTime": "10:35 AM"
     },
     "taskTimer":
     {
        "id": 789,
        "name": "My Task",
        "startTime": "10:45 AM"
     }
  }
}
```

The key points here are:

- "timers" is an object -- NOT an array
- The sub-objects are also set i.e. "projectTimer" and "taskTimer"

If I set my SELECT statement to the following, it works by giving me both projectTimer and taskTimer sub-objects

```
SELECT c.timers
FROM Collection c
WHERE c.id = 123
```

But the following returns nothing. I don't understand why because it seems like a really simple JOIN:

```
SELECT t.projectTimer
FROM Collection c
JOIN t IN c.timers
WHERE c.id = 123
```

Any idea where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: probably because you don't have `t.projecttimer` before you do the join? try `select c.id from collection c join t in c.timers where c.id=123` and see if that gives you something

Comment: That gives me nothing either. I'm not clear about what the problem is though. Could you please elaborate a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: well, I'm not expert in this. just tried to adapt this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588163/documentdb-where-clause-within-collection

Comment: I'm actually following the rules mentioned in that example. At least, I think I am following them. Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to do a `JOIN` on something that's not an array.

If, instead, you reworked your document slightly:

```
  {
    "id": "123",
    "timers": [
      {
        "projectTimer": {
          "id": 234,
          "name": "My Project",
          "startTime": "10:35 AM"
        }
      },
      {
        "taskTimer": {
          "id": 789,
          "name": "My Task",
          "startTime": "10:45 AM"
        }
      }
    ],
  }
```

You'd then be able to do a `JOIN` like:

```
select value t
from collection c
join t in c.timers
where c.id = "123"
```

Which would return each of the timers in the array:

```
[
  {
    "projectTimer": {
      "id": 234,
      "name": "My Project",
      "startTime": "10:35 AM"
    }
  },
  {
    "taskTimer": {
      "id": 789,
      "name": "My Task",
      "startTime": "10:45 AM"
    }
  }
]
```

Note the use of `VALUE` in the query, to strip away the containing `t` variable.

Comment: So, JOIN will only work if the property is an array. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct - you're essentially unwinding the array.

Comment: Super useful information. Thank you. I was able to get this to work without changing the structure with this: `SELECT c.timers.projectTimer, c.timers.taskTimer FROM Collection c WHERE c.id = 123`. I'm glad I kept the question open though. Thanks again for the very useful pointer!