# IN equivalent for cosmos db subquery

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to get all results from a query that contains a specific value from a subquery.

Give me all records for all trainees where Instructor1 has been instructor at least once

::UPDATE::

So it appears that my data has to be in an array in order to join it.  Is there any way to join this without updating all my data?

```
SELECT * FROM root r 
WHERE trainee.userName 
IN (
    select value trainee.userName from r 
    WHERE instructor.userName="instructor1"
)
```

```
{
    "trainee": {
        "id": null,
        "givenName": "Test",
        "surname": "Trainee",
        "userName": "trainee1"
    },
    "instructor": {
        "id": null,
        "givenName": "Test",
        "surname": "Instructor",
        "userName": "instructor1"
    }
}
```

Comment: What about using `JOIN` or `HAVING`?

Answer (score 1):

I see that this has been answered in another post.  You cannot JOIN on data unless it is in an ARRAY.   [DocumentDb SELECT with JOIN not returning anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42618905/documentdb-select-with-join-not-returning-anything)

Answer (score 0):

This is done using JOIN in Cosmos DB. Take a look at this article on [Correlated Sub Queries in Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-subquery) that has examples.

Comment: thanks for that.  I've been looking through there.  I'm having JOIN issues unless I wrap my data in [ ].  I guess I missing the syntax to JOIN without that structure.

Comment: If it isn't a child object would that be considered an inner document join?  which I don't believe is possible?